# Storing data inside Android/data/pkgname

Tags: android

I am trying to add data into a folder which is inside Android/Data/packagename. So I am trying this out:

```
String tempsubdirtest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/files/Images";


        File subdirecttest = new File(tempsubdirtest);

        if (!subdirecttest.exists())
        {
            subdirecttest.mkdirs();
        }
```

The question is that is there an easy way to reduce the code for:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName()
```

instead of me typing /Android/data/ +getPackName etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this existing method [getExternalCacheDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir())

This will return the directory path plus a **cache** folder.
So in your case, you can just exclude that cache path.

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/cache
```

You might gonna check this, which will return something similar to what you want.

```
String pathImage = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/files/Pictures
```

Comment: I have added an example code of how to get Image path. You wanna check that.